# How will I know when my tag wiki contribution has been approved?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, rejected-edits

How long do changes to wikis for tags take to be approved?

I have written a wiki for a tag, it has not been approved yet, and I want to know what notification I get to tell me if it has been approved or rejected.

Also if it is rejected, do I get any notification of the fact that it is rejected or I am I just told it's a no?

Comment: If it is [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/217135) it is already rejected.

Comment: Is their any way of making it better so that it is approved or do I lose my opportunity to alter this tag?

Comment: The reviewers gave hints on why they rejected your suggestion. So you could start with addressing that. But you have to submit a new/ better edit. You can't improve a handled suggestion. Also I suggest you ask on the [Meta of Unix and Linux](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/) instead. That community knows best what they want with their wiki's.

Comment: Why did I get no notification that it was rejected. You guys found it better then I did. Is there a way of turning the notification setting on so that I am told if it is rejected?

Comment: And to be complete: you can find your own sugestions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/259450/jake-symons?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)

Comment: You don't ever get notifications for negative events. That is by design.

Comment: So, to find out what goes on I have to look on the link you sent me but I have to do that for every single website I am signed up on that I have made wikis on to see if they have been rejected or not? That seems quite a long process, why is their no way of shortening it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I don't think many users go editing wiki's on lot of sites so building that feature would benefit only a small group of users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no notification if your tag wiki has been rejected. You have to look at your suggestions under the all actions tab on your profile.
You can find all your wiki posts their as well as the reasons why they have been rejected.